# How scaffold Durandal, Breeze in SPA app with VS 2012

Tags: breeze, scaffolding, durandal, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, hottowel

I'm starting to develop an application based on Hot Towel project template. The question is how I can scaffold Durandal?

I want to perform code generation like [mvc scaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/), but for SPA using Hot Towel template, to accelerate the development of the CRUD pages

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Hot Towel is a full VS template, what do you mean scaffold? The template has everything in it already.

Comment: I want to perform code generation like mvc scaffolding (http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/), but for SPA using Hot Towel template, to accelerate the development of the CRUD pages

Comment: I do not believe Durandal has an equivalent package. You will have to do that work yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box the Hot Towel project template is based on Durandal, Knockout, and Breeze.  Durandal and Knockout work seamlessly with the MVVM pattern, and not the MVC or other MV* patterns.

The approach is not that different from the MVC pattern, my best suggestion for you on this is to follow what is given for you, and if it is not found to meet your needs, you can look at some other libraries or frameworks such as Angular.js or Ember.js.

There are more out there, but this would be the simplest way to decide if you are using what best fits your needs.

By the way, in addition to the pattern, it is worth noting that MVC scaffolding in an ASP.NET MVC project is all done on the server side with ASP.NET MVC controllers and basically generated views.  Using a templating engine you could easily replicate the same functionality across all of your views by creating each of the CRUD operations (Create view, Read (details) view, Update (edit) view, and Delete views)

One thing that makes JavaScript libraries unique is that you can also combine all four of these functions into one and utilize a templating engine to share the functionality.